# Quick way to know if the image asset is landscape or portrait using ALAssetLibrary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I get asset using ALAssetLibrary. Is there way to know is this image landscape or portrait not loading the image but having only asset?

[asset **thumbnail**] returns (75,75) size image,so its doesn't help.

To load **fullScreen** or **fullResolution** image and compare its width and height is to **heavy**.

To load **metadata** and than **pixelHeight** and **Width** is also heavy.

So can someone help?

Comment: How about `aspectRatioThumbnail`?

Comment: Thanks) Didn't know about that, but it is available only in iOS 5.0. Need something like that but in lower version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the orientation method of ALAssetRepresentation (available since iOS 4.0).
So your call would be something like this.

ALAssetOrientation orientation = [[asset defaultRepresentation] orientation];

The performance of this call should be fine.

Cheers,

Hendrik